# Flash back button support

Tags: flash, seo

Does anyone know if there's a Flash (ActionScript) library for providing back button support?

The GotMilk site does this. I was hoping there's a Flash library for this so I can provide and train a customer of mine to utilize this technique to build a whole site in flash.

http://gotmilk.com/
http://gotmilk.com/#/gotmilkbrand/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best solutions is SWFAddress:

http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/

You just need to include the javascript on your page and register a listener with the SWFAddress.as class. Download the full package on the site; there's a few really good demos. Quite easy to implement if you structure your Flash site well.

Here are some example in which I've used it recently:

http://gravisfootwear.com/

http://pth.amnestyusa.org/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a library, but I imagine it hooks in with JavaScript to update the window.location.hash property.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [this article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/deep_linking.html).  It describes how you can implement deep linking in Flash using the hash of the page's URL.

I've used deep linking in one of my Flex applications.  It is a nice way of not-only supporting the back/forward button, but also to allow "pages" of your flash to be bookmarked and linked to.

Answer (score 0):

I know that Flex can do this using, well, here's some sample code:

[Using the browser history to track application state changes](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showDetails&loc=en_US&postId=209&productId=2)

I never did implement this in my Flex application, but I kept planning to (until the project was canceled).